# How to filter all the highest numbers

Tags: swift, filter

I'm trying to filter out the highest number in an array

```
var a = [2, 2, 1, 1, 0]

var b = a.max()

print(b!) // 2
```

How do I get all the highest numbers?

```
print (b!) // 2, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `max()` and `filter(_ isIncluded:)`:

```
let array: [Int] = [2, 2, 1, 1, 0]
let maxElement: Int? = array.max()

if let unwrappedMaxElement: Int = maxElement {
  let arrayContainingMaxElements: [Int] = array.filter { $0 == unwrappedMaxElement }

  print(arrayContainingMaxElements) // [2, 2]
}
```

Comment: how would I go about make a calculation in that array that would plus the number with the number of times the number is present.

[2, 2] should become [3] and [2, 2, 2] should become [4]

does that make any sense?

Comment: You'd use `count` to get the number of elements in `arrayContainingMaxElements` and then add `1`. Not sure if this is what you mean?